# find yearly cumsum of a variable in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, tidyverse, cumsum

In my code below, i would like to find the `cumsum` for each year. Right now, `Variable A` is being `summed` for the entire duration. Any help would be appreciated.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
set.seed(50)
DF <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to= as.Date("2003-12-31"), by="day"),
                       A = runif(1095, 0,10))
DF1 <- DF %>% 
  mutate(Year = year(date), Month = month(date), JDay = yday(date)) %>%
  filter(between(Month,5,10)) %>%
  group_by(Year, JDay) %>% 
  mutate(Precipitation = cumsum(A))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue here is with your grouping clause. Specifically, as there are as many distinct combinations of `Year` and `JDay` in your data as there are rows in `DF`, the subsequent `cumsum` operation inside `mutate` will simply return the same value as the input column, `A`.  I believe the following should give you what you're after

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(50)
DF <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to= as.Date("2003-12-31"), by="day"),
                 A = runif(1095, 0,10))
DF1 <- DF %>% 
  mutate(Year = year(date), Month = month(date), JDay = yday(date)) %>%
  filter(between(Month,5,10)) %>%
  arrange(Year, JDay) %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  mutate(Precipitation =  cumsum(A)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# illustrate that Precipitation does indeed give the cumulative value of A for
# each year by printing the first 5 observations for each year in DF1
DF1 %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  slice(1:5)
#> # A tibble: 15 x 6
#> # Groups:   Year [3]
#>    date           A  Year Month  JDay Precipitation
#>    <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>
#>  1 2001-05-01 6.25   2001     5   121          6.25
#>  2 2001-05-02 0.188  2001     5   122          6.43
#>  3 2001-05-03 5.37   2001     5   123         11.8 
#>  4 2001-05-04 5.55   2001     5   124         17.4 
#>  5 2001-05-05 5.15   2001     5   125         22.5 
#>  6 2002-05-01 2.95   2002     5   121          2.95
#>  7 2002-05-02 6.75   2002     5   122          9.71
#>  8 2002-05-03 7.77   2002     5   123         17.5 
#>  9 2002-05-04 8.13   2002     5   124         25.6 
#> 10 2002-05-05 5.58   2002     5   125         31.2 
#> 11 2003-05-01 9.98   2003     5   121          9.98
#> 12 2003-05-02 8.24   2003     5   122         18.2 
#> 13 2003-05-03 6.13   2003     5   123         24.4 
#> 14 2003-05-04 5.22   2003     5   124         29.6 
#> 15 2003-05-05 9.81   2003     5   125         39.4
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to show that the code does indeed produce a data frame wherein `Precipitation`  represents the cumulative value of `A` for each `Year`. If the output is not what you are after, could you please provide a reprex that shows what you expect to get?

Comment: I restarted my R session and load only `lubridate` and `dplyr` packages and it started working. Previously i had the `tidyverse`, `tidyr` packages loaded as well. I don't know why but am thinking there might be some sort of confusion among the packages which is why i was not getting the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `JDay` from grouping variables

```
DF1 <- DF %>% 
  mutate(Year = year(date), Month = month(date), JDay = yday(date)) %>%
  filter(between(Month,5,10)) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  mutate(Precipitation = cumsum(A)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: I removed my previous comment- i had a couple of other packages (`tidyverse`, `tidyr`) loaded as well which i believe was the sole reason of not getting the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` solution for that. If you want the cumsum for each year, but show only the interval from month 5 to 10, this would be `data.table` code for that:

```r
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
library(data.table)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'data.table'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:lubridate':
#> 
#>     hour, isoweek, mday, minute, month, quarter, second, wday, week,
#>     yday, year
set.seed(50)
DF <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to= as.Date("2003-12-31"), by="day"),
                 A = runif(1095, 0,10))

data.table(DF)[, `:=` (Year = year(date), Month = month(date), JDay = yday(date))][, Precipitation := cumsum(A), by=Year][between(Month, 5, 10)][]
#>            date         A Year Month JDay Precipitation
#>   1: 2001-05-01 6.2465000 2001     5  121      568.9538
#>   2: 2001-05-02 0.1877191 2001     5  122      569.1416
#>   3: 2001-05-03 5.3717570 2001     5  123      574.5133
#>   4: 2001-05-04 5.5457454 2001     5  124      580.0591
#>   5: 2001-05-05 5.1508288 2001     5  125      585.2099
#>  ---                                                   
#> 548: 2003-10-27 0.1979292 2003    10  300     1479.8115
#> 549: 2003-10-28 6.7286553 2003    10  301     1486.5402
#> 550: 2003-10-29 8.7215420 2003    10  302     1495.2617
#> 551: 2003-10-30 8.2572257 2003    10  303     1503.5190
#> 552: 2003-10-31 9.6567923 2003    10  304     1513.1757
```

If you want the cumsum for the months 5-10 only, you would put the filter before calculating the cumsum:

```
data.table(DF)[, `:=` (Year = year(date), Month = month(date), JDay = yday(date))][between(Month, 5, 10)][, Precipitation := cumsum(A), by=Year][]
#>            date         A Year Month JDay Precipitation
#>   1: 2001-05-01 6.2465000 2001     5  121      6.246500
#>   2: 2001-05-02 0.1877191 2001     5  122      6.434219
#>   3: 2001-05-03 5.3717570 2001     5  123     11.805976
#>   4: 2001-05-04 5.5457454 2001     5  124     17.351722
#>   5: 2001-05-05 5.1508288 2001     5  125     22.502550
#>  ---                                                   
#> 548: 2003-10-27 0.1979292 2003    10  300    916.597973
#> 549: 2003-10-28 6.7286553 2003    10  301    923.326629
#> 550: 2003-10-29 8.7215420 2003    10  302    932.048171
#> 551: 2003-10-30 8.2572257 2003    10  303    940.305396
#> 552: 2003-10-31 9.6567923 2003    10  304    949.962189
```